# Get Playwright to Wait Until Title Contains Specific Text

Tags: python, web-scraping, playwright, playwright-python

I'm new at playwright and I'm a little stuck.  I'm scraping a site that has a lot of back and forth Javascript.  I want my parsing logic to wait until the the title of the page is populated with a particular value, which would indicate that the page has loaded enough to parse.

Here are the relevant parts of my code.

```py
        with sync_playwright() as pw_firefox:
            browser = pw_firefox.firefox.launch(headless=True, timeout=self.timeout)
            context = browser.new_context(viewport={"width": 1920, "height": 1080},
                                          extra_http_headers=HEADERS,
                                          strict_selectors=False)
            page = context.new_page()

            # Go to url and wait for the page to load
            page.goto(final_url)
            html = page.content()
```

Is there a way to use the `wait_for_selector()` or `wait_for_function()` methods to get playwright to wait until the `<title>` is populated with a specific value?
Thanks!

Comment: Could you share the actual site, or something similar? It's possible to do this with `wait_for_function`, but there may be a more stable way to determine when the page is loaded, which is use case specific.

Comment: I'm looking to scrape TikTok metadata.  I had a scraper which used to work which waited for the title to appear with the user's account name.  However, after doing some experimentation, what's happening is a login box is appearing which is preventing me from getting the info I'm looking for.

Comment: Here's the repo: https://github.com/geniza-ai/scrapeomatic

Comment: I have a branch there where I'm working on this.  I can get the account metadata, but I'm not able to get the video metadata yet.

Comment: Can you share a [mcve] in the question itself? Thanks. Does my answer help? If not, I don't have a TikTok account so if it requires login, I probably won't be able to help much.

Comment: @ggorlen, Thank you very much for your assistance.  Here's what I've been able to figure out.  If you attempt to access a profile page on TikTok, you get a login modal.  That login modal has a button with the text `Continue as guest`.    My new strategy is to have playwright click on that modal, which causes it to disappear.  Once it disappears, TikTok loads the video list.

Comment: For additional fun, TikTok uses dynamically generated CSS classes to identify the button.  However, I've found that if I can get playwright to click the button, it works.   I just can't figure out how to get the button clicked.  I updated the code in the question.

Comment: Hmm--thanks for the info and context. The problem is, your update sort of invalidates the existing answers, including the one you accepted, since you're now asking about [problem X rather than problem Y](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem/233676#233676). I'd suggest rolling back the edit so the question makes sense to future visitors again, then posting a new question with clear context. In the new question, share the updated code (ideally fully runnable, with a URL) and the explanation you've added in your last comments. Thanks.

Comment: Thanks.  I posted a new question here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77873841/using-playwright-to-find-and-click-on-button-with-dynamic-css-scraping-tiktok

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> "To wait until the title of the page is populated "

To address above problem statement,you may simply use page assertion [to_have_title](https://playwright.dev/python/docs/api/class-pageassertions#page-assertions-to-have-title):

```
expect(page).to_have_title("new title",timeout=5000)
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if blocking until the title changes is necessarily the best way to determine whether the site loads for your use case, but here's how to do it on an example page that changes its title after 4 seconds:

```py
from playwright.sync_api import expect, sync_playwright  # 1.40.0


sample_html = """<!DOCTYPE html><html><head>
<title>original title</title></head><body><script>
setTimeout(() => document.title = "new title", 4000);
</script></body></html>"""

with sync_playwright() as p:
    browser = p.chromium.launch()
    page = browser.new_page()
    page.set_content(sample_html)
    print(page.title())  # => original title
    page.wait_for_function('document.title === "new title"')
    print(page.title())  # => new title
    browser.close()
```