# Using Playwright to Find and Click on Button with Dynamic CSS (Scraping TikTok)

Tags: python, playwright, playback, playwright-python, tiktok

I am working on an OSS scraper for various social media platforms.  I have a small issue with TikTok.  I can successfully scrape the profile and get metadata.  However, I also want to pull back metadata about videos associated with the profile.  The video information is contained in an XHR call.

However, after loading the page, a login modal appears. I've found that if I click on the `Continue as guest` button, the modal disappears and the XHR request is executed.  To make things difficult, TikTok uses a generated CSS style for the button.

I've gotten this to work: `page.click('.css-dcgpa6-DivBoxContainer');`  However, the identifier changes every few minutes.

So my question is, is there a way to:

1. Find the button's css class by using the fact that it contains known text?  And then:
2. Click on this button using playwright?

Here is my code:

```py
    def collect(self, username: str) -> dict:
        _xhr_calls = []
        final_url = f"{TIKTOK_BASE_URL}{username}"

        def intercept_response(response):
            """Capture all background requests and save them."""
            # We can extract details from background requests
            if response.request.resource_type == "xhr":
                logging.debug(f"Appending {response.request.url}")
                _xhr_calls.append(response)
            return response

        with sync_playwright() as pw_firefox:
            browser = pw_firefox.firefox.launch(headless=True, timeout=self.timeout)
            context = browser.new_context(viewport={"width": 1920, "height": 1080},
                                          strict_selectors=False)
            page = context.new_page()

            # Block cruft
            page.route("**/*", AsyncUtils.intercept_route)

            # Enable background request intercepting:
            page.on("response", intercept_response)

            # Navigate to the profile page
            page.goto(final_url, referer=final_url)
            page.wait_for_timeout(1500)
            # Get the page content
            html = page.content()

            # Parse it.
            soup = BeautifulSoup(html, 'html.parser')

            # The user info is contained in a large JS object called __UNIVERSAL_DATA_FOR_REHYDRATION__.
            tt_script = soup.find('script', attrs={'id': "__UNIVERSAL_DATA_FOR_REHYDRATION__"})

            try:
                raw_json = json.loads(tt_script.string)
            except AttributeError as exc:
                raise JSONDecodeError(
                    f"ScrapeOMatic was unable to parse the data from TikTok user {username}. Please try again.\n {exc}") from exc

            user_data = raw_json['__DEFAULT_SCOPE__']['webapp.user-detail']['userInfo']['user']
            stats_data = raw_json['__DEFAULT_SCOPE__']['webapp.user-detail']['userInfo']['stats']

            """
            button = page.get_by_text('p:has-text("Continue as guest")')
            guest_button = page.locator(selector="div", has=button)
            if guest_button is not None:
                logging.debug("Clicking button.")
                guest_button.click(no_wait_after=True)

            # page.click('.css-dcgpa6-DivBoxContainer');
            # page.click('.emuynwa3');
            # page.wait_for_timeout(500)
            # page.keyboard.press("PageDown")
            # page.wait_for_timeout(500)
            # page.keyboard.press("PageDown")
            """

            data_calls = [f for f in _xhr_calls if "list" in f.url]
            for call in data_calls:
                logging.debug(call.json())

            profile_data = {
                'sec_id': user_data['secUid'],
                'id': user_data['id'],
                'is_secret': user_data['secret'],
                'username': user_data['uniqueId'],
                'bio': emoji.demojize(user_data['signature'], delimiters=("", "")),
                'avatar_image': user_data['avatarMedium'],
                'following': stats_data['followingCount'],
                'followers': stats_data['followerCount'],
                'language': user_data['language'],
                'nickname': emoji.demojize(user_data['nickname'], delimiters=("", "")),
                'hearts': stats_data['heart'],
                'region': user_data['region'],
                'verified': user_data['verified'],
                'heart_count': stats_data['heartCount'],
                'video_count': stats_data['videoCount'],
                'is_verified': user_data['verified'],
                # 'videos': videos,
                # 'hashtags': self.hashtags
            }

            return profile_data
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.  Also here is a link to the GitHub repo: https://github.com/geniza-ai/scrapeomatic

Thanks!!

Comment: Look at the [documentation](https://playwright.dev/python/docs/intro) for help.

Comment: Gee that was helpful.   I'm really glad I asked.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While I am no python developer (and wont shame myself with trying to brush off my old python knowledge), I can provide a pseudocode-esque way of achieving what you need.

Your questions says:

1. Find the button's css class by using the fact that it contains known text? And then:

2.Click on this button using playwright?

If you already know the buttons text, you dont need its class. You have the text so find it via this identifier:

`await expect(page.get_by_text("continue as guest")).to_be_visible()'

Then just click it.